# SSH login to gcp instance from unknown address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just logged into one of my Debian GCP instances and it reported the last login was from an IP address owned by google that I am not familiar with (not me and I have not given third parties access). Has this happened to anyone on GCP before?

Comment: Did you use the Google Cloud Shell?

Comment: Or use the Google Cloud Console GUI **ssh** button, which uses Google Cloud IAP, to access your instance?

Comment: Provided that 1) you have not enabled password-based login; 2) you only allows SSH key pair login access; 3) you have protected the SSH private key; it is highly unlikely that someone has broken into your system via SSH. Note; with the correct Google Cloud IAM roles, another user can install their own SSH public key (which would not generate your warning message).